# How to request removal of a pole in Iowa owned by Mediacom

Tags: removal, pole

I am running into a situation where I need a pole removed from my yard where Mediacom is the only company that has a main line on it.  This is at the end of their run and no wires are attached to any houses from it.  I have a new driveway going in and this pole sits in the middle of the path.  I want them to completely remove there main line and terminate it at the pole that is feeding this pole.  I have tried calling the city and they told me I have to have Mediacom remove it since Mediacom owns it.  I call Mediacom and request to talk to their construction department to get the main line removed.  Mediacom tells me they don't have a construction department.  The only number I have is to their main number for requesting service or tech support.  Basically a Tier 1 that won't forward requests to any other department, etc.  This has been going on for months and I am getting nowhere.  Does anyone know a phone number I can call where I can get some action to be taken by Mediacom to remove their main line and possibly the pole?

Comment: Try a local tv/radio station.  Some of them have a consumer show where they go to big companies not listening to the locals.  One phone from them usually works.

Comment: They have a Right-of-Way, since they have a pole. They have zero incentive to give that up, so you should change the path of the new driveway to avoid the pole. In any case, this is not particularly on-topic here.

Comment: It appears you need local legal advice (or helpful termites that like creosoted wood). You might also try a local news outlet, to see if they can publicize the issue. This does not seem to be a DIY project.

Comment: Any possibility the pole used to have other utilities (electricity, telephone) that have since been removed but the pole still in place because of Mediacom? If that's the case, Mediacom can't actually remove the pole even if they remove the wires.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a local ordinance and contract issue, which would be off topic here. Good luck.

Comment: Check wih your friends and neighbors to see if any of them use Mediacom and look at their bill.  They usually have phone munbers to call for maintenance and damage to facilities.

Comment: Update.  I was able to get a Job Order # to get someone out to take a look at it.  Hopefully I hear back within a week or two.  It was worse than pulling teeth since you have to go through their first line customer service to get a maintenance request created.  After talking to 10+ customer service reps I found one that was willing to create the request ticket instead of telling me they can't do anything since I don't have service at my address and then hanging up on me.  Their customer service really sucks!

Answer (score 2):

Contact your city's franchise authority. They may be able to help directly, and if not, will most likely have contact information.

I'm in Iowa and have used the one in my town years ago to handle an issue with an unresponsive Mediacom.

Comment: The problem is the City won't remove the pole because Mediacom is still on it.  If I can get Mediacom off the pole, the City will remove it.  And the City has requested something similar in the past from Mediacom and they were given the run around and basically told me "Good Luck getting Mediacom out there to take the Main line off".  I personally wouldn't have a problem with taking it down myself but since Mediacom has their main line on it I can run into some legal issues with that.

Comment: @MikeK. Utilities enter into a "franchise agreement" (a contract) with a city in order to gain the privilege of placing poles and wires in/under/over city rights-of-way, ie streets and sidewalks. The city's franchise authority (mayor, city manager, or other executive) may be able to provide contact info for a utility representative that you can't access via published customer service channels. You may have to make a request under the Iowa Open Records laws to obtain this information.